# application wide global variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

In **Rails**, where should I define the variable which can be recognized by every layer of Rails stacks.

For example, I would like to have a `CUSTOMER_NAME='John'` variable which can be accessed in **helper**, **rake** task, **controller** and **model**. Where should I define this variable in **Rails** app?

I am using **Rails v2.3.2**

Comment: What you are asking about is not variable, but a constant, what means: it cannot be set from within application. I was misleaded here by search engine because the wrong term is used here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In an initializer in `/app/config/initializers` all .rb files in here get loaded, I usually create one called preferences.rb for things like this.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files

Answer (score 15):

An alternative approach is to set a key on the config object in `config/application.rb`, like so:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
   # ...
   config.my_key = 'some "global" value'
end
```

You can then access `my_key` from anywhere in your app with just this:

```
MyApp::Application.config.my_key
```

Also, Mike Perham has described a similar, though a more comprehensive approach [in his blog post](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/11/23/configuration-for-rails-the-right-way/).

Comment: Isn't that a constant but not variable? Could it be changed in an application during run time?

Comment: It's a variable and can be changed during runtime.

Answer (score 9):

You want a true global constant? Use `::COSTUMER_NAME`.
You want a true global variable? Use `$COSTUMER_NAME` (discouraged).
You want a request-global variable? Use the `Hash` in the `#env` method.

Comment: You mean create a linux server wide global variable?

Comment: `ENV` and `#env` are two different things. `ENV` is the global constant representing the Unix environment. `#env` is a controller method that returns the current rack environment.

Comment: I do ::TESTABC = 'hola' and try to print from a view ::TESTABC and it says is not defined

Comment: Why is $CUSTOMER_NAME discouraged ?

Comment: `$CUSTOMER_NAME` is a process-global variable. `::COSTUMER_NAME` is a constant, so Ruby will at least complain when you reassign things to it.